# java classpath colon(":") in file name

Tags: java, command, classpath

I have a jar file in a folder, which has ":" in its name, like this:

`/Cubyz alpha 0.6.0: The Enlightened Update/main.jar`

I want to run it from outside the folder from command.

But it doesn't work because colon(":") is a reserved character.

I tried the following things so far:

`java -jar "/home/…/Cubyz alpha 0.6.0: The Enlightened Update/main.jar"`

`java -cp /home/…/Cubyz\ alpha 0.6.0\:\ The\ Enlightened\ Update/main.jar MainClass`

`java -cp "/home/…/Cubyz alpha 0.6.0: The Enlightened Update/main.jar" MainClass`

`java -cp "/home/…/Cubyz alpha 0.6.0\: The Enlightened Update/main.jar" MainClass`

All of them output `Error: Could not find or load main class`.

Is there any way I can escape the ":"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong command. If you would like to *run* the jar file, then you could call the following command:

`java -jar /home/…/Cubyz\ alpha\ 0.6.0\:\ The\ Enlightened\ Update/main.jar`

This escapes the space and the colon characters by using the backslash (\) escape character.

You could also use apostrophes, so that the command is seen as a string and in that case you don't have to escape the special characters:

`java -jar '/home/…/Cubyz alpha 0.6.0: The Enlightened Update/main.jar'`

Or with quotes (depending on terminal / OS being used):

`java -jar "/home/…/Cubyz alpha 0.6.0: The Enlightened Update/main.jar"`

Comment: That's what I tried first, and it also didn't work.
I did some further testing and it also seems to only work for folders that don't contain ":".

Comment: Yeah, if it is possible for you to remove/replace the colon (and space) characters, then I would suggest to do so. Makes the life a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: Surely I can do that, but I hoped there was a better way.

Comment: I understand. I find it odd though because I tried it with the `java -jar` command myself (on a Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop version) and it worked for me. I think it should also work on Windows. Is the jar file created by you? Or is it someone else's (e.g. downloaded) ? Because 1 more thing I can think of is that the `Main-Class` header is not set (properly) in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. Could that be the case? Here's more information about that, just in case: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: No that is not the case. If I `cd` into the directory and run `java -jar main.jar` from there everything works fine. Maybe it got fixed in newer java versions? I only tested it on java 8 and java 11.

Comment: Hm, no it should work. I also used JDK 11 (AdoptOpenJDK HotSpot). What terminal are you using to call the command? And I assume you use Windows 10?

Comment: I use the standard terminal in Linux Mint 19.
My java version is `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)`

Comment: Hm, well it seems to be a more of an OS / Filesystem thingy and not Java specific. I tried it with  the OpenJDK version 11.0.8+10 and that worked too. So I'm out of ideas. Linux Mint terminal might be interpreting colon (and other special chars) differently. I can only suggest to rename the path to the file / move the file somewhere else, to a path without spaces, colons etc. But that doesn't answer your question... sorry for that